# How to round a number in JavaScript only if necessary

Tags: javascript

I want to round a number in JavaScript but to `2 decimal` places but only if necessary.

For example `4.5` to be `4.50` and `3.331` to be `3.331`.

I have tried using `Math.round(number / 100) * 100` but when number is `4.5` it gives me `4.5` and I want it to be `4.50`.

I have tried using `.toFixed(2)`, but when number is `3.331` it will fix it to `3.33`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you have more use cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: @DevsiOdedra dup target doesn't address this use case

Comment: That's not rounding a number - that's padding it. Rounding means that you remove some of the least digits and adjust the remainder up or down to account for them.

Comment: It doesn't look like a rounding problem. In the end, you're just padding with zeroes when the number has less than two decimals.

Comment: why stays `3.331`?

Comment: @NinaScholz I think the logic is - have *at least* two decimal places but if you have more, keep them. So, it's not actually rounding.

Comment: Would you have whole numbers, e.g., `5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the fixed value change and select the kind of formatting.

```js
function format(f) {
    return f === +f.toFixed(2)
        ? f.toFixed(2)
        : f.toString()
}

console.log([4.5, 3.331, 3].map(format));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex check the digits after the dot. if it is less than 2 then use `toFixed(2)`, else do nothing.

```js
function f(n) {
    let diff = Number(n) - Math.floor(Number(n));
    return /\.[0-9]{2,}/.test(diff.toString()) ? n : n.toFixed(2)
}
const nums = [3.331, 2.5, 3].map(f)
console.log(nums)
```

Comment: What about `num = 3`?

Comment: Since OP didn't ask it, that's why I ignored it.

Comment: The new solution doesn't work like before - `2.5` turns into `2.5`

Comment: Now it returns different types - sometimes it's an integer, other times a string...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply conditionallu `toFixed()` method:

```js
const numbers = [4.5, 3.331];
const floated = numbers.map(
  n => {
    const floatLen = n.toString().split('.')[1];
    if(floatLen){
      if(floatLen.toString().length < 2){
        return n.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  return n;
  }
);
console.log(floated);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an String format and not a rounding problem:

```
var value = 4 + '.';
var [num, dec] = value.split('.');

if (dec.length < 2) {
  dec = (dec + '00').substring(0, 2);
}
console.log(`${num}.${dec}`);
```

Runnable snippet:

```js
function format(value) {
  var [num, decimal] = (value + '.').split('.');
  
  if (decimal.length < 2) {
    decimal = (decimal + '00').substring(0, 2);
  }

  return `${num}.${decimal}`;  
}

console.log([4, 4.5, 3.331].map(format));
```

4 -> 4.00

4.5 -> 4.50

3.331 -> 3.331

Comment: Not directly related but `num` and `digit` are confusing names. A digit *is* a number. Also, having a digit with any length that's not `1` is impossible.

Comment: I don't see the limit to 1, have to rename the variable names

Comment: A *digit* is a single symbol that creates a number - `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, and `0` are all the digits in decimal. Hex also has `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, for example. A number is composed of one or more digits, so each of these. That's why you have a "two digit number" like `42` or `55`, or "three digit number" - `123`, `216`, `715`, etc.

Comment: I see, you not referring to the variable.